# Make margin extend containing element not escape it?

Tags: html, css, margin

When I apply a margin to an element rather than extending its containing element it creates margin outside of it. So with the code below there is a space between the divs's coloured background.

Why does this happen? It would seem more logical to me for the containing div to be expanded (so im the code example there would be no white space and the coloured 'bars' would be fatter).

Is there a way with CSS I can stop it happening?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrJgm

```
<div class="one">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="three">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
.one {
  background: red;
}
.two {
  background: green;
}
.three {
  background: gold;
}
```

UPDATE Sorry I dont think I was clear. I understand that the margin on the paragraph tag is causing the white space but what I dont understand is why the margin isnt 'pushing back' the containing div (so it would look the same as if a padding had been applied to the containing div).

Comment: I think you're confusing margin and padding

Comment: @ExtPro He is not resetting the styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you updated your question, I think whats troubling you is [Collapsing Margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

Solution? Use `overflow: auto;` on the parent element.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKH4P/)

---

**If you are speaking about the white space in the demo as I am not seeing any margins used in your code.. Than below is the answer..**

You are not resetting browser default styles..

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpgDm)

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   outline: 0; /* Optional */
}
```

Here I am using `*` selector which selects all the elements, and am using `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` to reset the browser defaults..

---

Some do not use `*` selector as they find it bad from a performance point of view, so if that's the case you can use [CSS Stylesheet Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

---

**If you are using margins in your code than please refer this answer...**

If you are aware of the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), `border`, `padding` and `margin` are counted outside of the element and not inside.

[image]

So in this case you might like to have `padding` and not `margin`.

Though, you can alter the behavior of CSS Box Model by using [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property set to `border-box` or `padding-box` which will count the `border` and `padding` inside of the element rather counting outside of it..

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph tag has margin on it by default. So if you want to get rid of the margin you need to set it to 0 and to expand the paragraph container you need add padding (pads inside of the container), margin is used for outside of the container

```
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bqgyd